# Terraform SSH Putty Challenge

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Hi Im trying to automate provisioning via Terraform to an EC2 Instance. But my Login Never Completes. From My Understanding I should export my AWS PEM Key to OpenSSH etc. (File Referenced in the Script) here are the key portions of my basic script. Eventually the Script Timesout due to Some SSH Issue. Can someone Give me some insight where i'm wrong at ?

```
connection {
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = "${file("PluralSight_Key_Pair3")}"   }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start"
    ]

aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH... aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec):   Host: 54.88.230.73 aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec):   User: ec2-user aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec):   Password: false aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec):   Private key: true aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false aws_instance.nginx: Still creating... (2m10s elapsed) aws_instance.nginx: Still creating... (2m20s elapsed) aws_instance.nginx: Still creating... (2m30s elapsed) aws_instance.nginx: Still creating... (2m40s elapsed) aws_instance.nginx (remote-exec): Connecting to remote

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_instance.nginx: timeout - last error: dial tcp 54.88.230.73:22: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 1):

Timeout sounds like a network issue, or waiting on a password for your SSH key.

- Ensure the instance is available via SSH from the computer running Terraform.
- You might want to check the instance's security group, maybe even run Terraform without the provisioner and try to connect manually with some debug output (`ssh -v`)
- You can get more information about what's going wrong by prepending `TF_LOG=debug` to your `terraform apply` command